# Questions: how can i change the output and serialize of xml and null values in web api asp.net 2?

Tags: c#, xml, webapi

I have created a web api and i am using microsoft sql server management studio for the database. what i want to do is to change the output of some null values in web api asp.net 2 and also i want  to serialize ouput like in the expectation.

what I get in the response of xml:

```
public List<Draft> Get()
        {
            List<Draft> list = new List<Draft>();
            string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Myconnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select UserID, Name, Mobile, Access, Date From tblTest", con);
            sqlconn.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery,sqlconn);
            SqlDataReader er = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
            while(er.Read())
            {
                draft.Add(new Draft()
                {
                   UserId = Convert.ToInt32(er.GetValue(0)),
                   Name = er.GetValue(1).ToString(),
                   Mobile = er.GetValue(2).ToString(),
                   Access = (er.GetValue(3) !=DBNull.Value)? Convert.ToInt32(er.GetValue(3)) : 0,
                   Date = (er.GetValue(4) ! = DBNull.Value)? Convert.ToDateTime(er.GetValue(4)) : (DateTime?)null
```

The ouput like this:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<ArrayOfDraft xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Draft>
<Access>0</Access>
<DateTime>2022-04-05T00:10:00</DateTime>
<Mobile>1234567891</Mobile>
<Name>Emily</Name>
<UserId>1</UserId>
</Draft>
<Draft>
<Access>2</Access>
<DateTime i:nil="true"/>
</Mobile>
<Name>Peter</Name>
<UserId>2</UserId>
</Draft>
```

Expectation:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<ArrayOfDraft xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Draft>
<UserId>1</UserId>
<Name>Emily</Name>
<Mobile>1234567891</Mobile>
<Access>0</Access>
<DateTime>2022-04-05T00:10:00</DateTime>
</Draft>
<UserId>2</UserId>
<Name>Peter</Name>
<Mobile></Mobile>
<Access>2</Access>
<DateTime>null</DateTime>
</Draft>
```

Class:

```
    public class TestClass
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public int Access { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

How to make the format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need add data contract in class to order the output

```
    [DataContract]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 3)]
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 4)]
        public int Access { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 5)]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```